# nvidia-375: GLX not working

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, opengl, shared-library

I have nvidia-375 driver installed on Ubuntu 16.10. However, there are problems with GPU acceleration e.g. in Chromium. When I run `glxinfo`, the following message appears:

```
glxinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The libary seems is present:

```
$ find /usr/lib -name libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
```

and `/usr/lib/nvidia-375` is referenced from `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`:

```
$ grep -R /usr/lib/nvidia-375 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf:/usr/lib/nvidia-375
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf:/usr/lib/nvidia-375
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` provides a clue:

```
[    12.871] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so: libnvidia-tls.so.375.39: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What could be causing the issue with loading the library?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I did not have `/etc/ld.so.conf`, so the library directories referenced from `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` were not added to `/etc/ld.so.cache`. After creating `/etc/ld.so.conf`:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

The errors are gone.